# GROUP BY equivalent predicate for NSFetchedResultsController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data

I'm trying to get a proper `NSFetchedRequest` to query the next unwatched episodes for a given TV-Show.
It should be put together in **one** request because I have to hand it to a NSFetchedResultsController.

```
My Model (CoreData):
 Show
   - Seasons:NSSet<Show>
 Season
   - Episodes:NSSet<Episode>
 Episode
   - first_aired:NSDate
   - watched:BOOL
```

There should be 1 (or 0) Episode returned for every show.

I can put this together with multiple requests.

for example: 
I set the `NSFetchedResultsController` up to fetch every `show`.
in `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` i iterate over every `Show` to get the latest `episode`

```
+(Episode *)nextAiringEpisodeForShow:(Show *)show{


    NSTimeInterval timeinterval = 0.0;
    NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:timeinterval];

    NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Episode"];
    request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"season.show = %@ AND watched = false AND season.seasonNumber > 0 AND first_aired > %@",show,date];
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"first_aired" ascending:NO];
    request.sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor];

    return  [[show.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:nil] lastObject];
}
```

The problem doing it this way:
There are Shows for which one has already watched all the episodes.
These will be displayed as `(null)` in the `UITableView` and there is no way to remove them from the `UITableView` because the `NSFetchedResultsController` is set as it's `dataSource`.
Furthermore there is no way to sort the `TableView` by `first_aired` when doing it this way.
Or am I missing something here?!

Comment: This is a bit of an evasive answer - but, are you obligated to use `NSFetchedResultsController`?  There may well be a way to construct a compound predicate to achieve the effect that you are looking for.  Alternatively if you did not use `NSFetchedResultsController`, you could execute your `NSFetchRequest` against the context and then filter the results to your heart's content; and use that as table view's data.  I've found that in some cases, `NSFetchedResultsController` makes more work for me as the developer for little performance gain with smallish data sets.

Comment: I thought about that. I think i will go ahead and try this approach then :) ... i just thought i had missed something as i'm pretty new to iOS development :)

Comment: thanks for the suggestion... it took like 10 minutes to write the whole Thing without the NSFetchedResultsController :))

Comment: @1b0t: It seems that your problem is solved. I did not see your comment before posting my answer ...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of fetching all shows in the fetched results controller, you could fetch only shows for which there is at least one unwatched episode. This should work with the following predicate (for the fetch request on "Show"):

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SUBQUERY(seasons, $x, ANY $x.episodes.watched == FALSE).@count > 0"]
```